# android can't connect to public WiFi

Tags: wi-fi

Have Essential with current OS. Just recently my phone won't connect to at least 2 public WiFi providers in Canada. One is Datavalet and the other is ConnectivityCheck. These are used in all Starbucks and many chain restaurants.

The familiar Starbucks connect page just keeps loading and loading in a loop. The others style the connect page just times out. Clearly from looking around others aren't having the same problem. A waiter once showed me how his Apple connected without issue. I have no problem at home, work or independent restaurants and cafes.

My assumption is that an App is interfereing but I haven't installed any new apps. This is a new problem as well, just noticed it in the last few weeks. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Try configuring your your wi-fi settings to use DHCP settings instead of static

Comment: Have you tried a Network Settings Reset within Android's settings menu? It will often clear up unusual network connectivity issues. Be aware this will reset all data settings in the device, including any stored WiFi passwords.